# What does setting a pointer to point at adress 0 do in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently practicing the understanding of pointers in C++ and what is syntactically correct and what is not. One of problems is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

int *pi;

pi = 0;

std::cout << pi ;

}
```

As I understand it, `pi` is a pointer which points to the value `*pi`.

After the assignment I make the compiler shows no errors, even though the type of `pi` is an integer pointer. I have researched it and found the null-pointer, which however is initiated by

`int *p = 0;`

and not with

```
int* p; 
p = 0;`
```

Does this assignment assign the pointer to the adress `0`?
Why is it not done like

`int *pi = (int *)0x28ff44;`

Also, even though there are no error warnings, I cannout output the value `*pi`.
The compiler says `Command terminated by signal 11`

Did I do something forbidden? If not, whats the reasoning behind it? Is it simply the null-pointer?

Comment: What would you expect `*pi` to do given that `pi` does not contain a value that you have any reason to expect contains any meaningful information?

Comment: `int *pi; pi = 0;` is equivalent to `int *pi = 0;`  Regarding the other questions, it will be beneficial to you in the long run to pick up a good textbook and read about pointers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz nothing, instead it gives out an error (?), I have included it into the question.

Comment: @RSahu that answers my question, thank you. Is it not allowed to output the value of a null-pointer? On Wikipedia it says: "a null pointer has a value reserved for indicating that the pointer does not refer to a valid object.", so why would it terminate instead without giving anything out?

Comment: @B.Swan You followed a pointer that "contained a value reserved for indicating that the pointer does not refer to a valid object", right? So the pointer definitely doesn't refer to a valid object. Yet you tried to output the value of the object it referred to, knowing that it didn't refer to a valid object. How could you expect anything sensible to happen?

Comment: @B.Swan: The "value" of `pi` is `pi`.  `*pi` isn't the "value of `pi`", it is the value pointed at by `pi`.  The first you can inspect even if the pointer value is NULL, the second is allowed only if the pointer value is valid.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you for pointing it out so clearly. I am satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a pointer to `0` is (typically) the same as setting it to `NULL` or `nullptr`, both of which are often 0 internally. There's really not much of a difference between assigning it immediately and assigning it on the line after, the compiler will probably figure out what's what and do exactly the same thing.

A null pointer is a perfectly valid thing to have in C++. What's "forbidden" is actually using it as if it wasn't NULL. For example:

```
int* pi = 0; // This is fine, the pointer can take any value you want.

if (pi != 0) // This is also fine. The pointer can be inspected without harm.
  ...

if (*pi != 0) // This is NOT fine and your code will crash!
  ...
```

The last example is called "dereferencing a NULL pointer" which is when things go horribly wrong. This is why you'll often see code that looks like:

```
if (pi != nullptr) // Ensure this pointer is not NULL.
```

Good C++ code will ensure that any pointer variables are initialized with *something* even if that something is `nullptr`. Uninitialized variables can take on random, invalid values that will cause crashes if you ever dare to dereference them.

Comment: `pi != 0` is fine because `pi` is NULL.  It would also be fine if `pi` were a valid pointer.  But it's not fine to compare "any value you want" -- comparing an invalid pointer value is actually undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt Even comparing pointer to pointer without de-referencing? I've seen code that badly abuses pointers by flipping bits on them so that the pointer is a really primitive form of a union and it can be used to store data as well as actual pointers. Not recommended, but sometimes this is necessary for performance reasons, such as inside VM code.

Comment: Some particular platforms may define the behavior, but the Standard makes it undefined.

Comment: @BenVoigt There's also the doubly linked list that has a single pointer for both left and right as it combines them with XOR. Not recommended, but also a situation where pointers are deliberately given "invalid" values.

Comment: The result of XORing two memory addresses is not a pointer, it's a pointer-sized integer (`uintptr_t`)

Comment: @BenVoigt If it's not in the official standard that's a fair point. I just haven't seen situations where compilers will prevent comparing arbitary pointer A to arbitrary pointer B.

Comment: It's not likely that the compiler would go out of its way to prevent it, but some platforms have distinct registers for pointers (perhaps called "index register" as opposed to "general-purpose accumulator") and will generate a hardware trap if an illegal value is loaded into one of these, and the Standard is written to allow compilers for these platforms to use pointer-only registers when they see pointer-typed variables.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's a really interesting feature to have in a CPU. I've only really done x86/x64, 68K, PowerPC and ARM, and I don't think any of those have that sort of thing going on, but I could be wrong. I usually try and treat my pointers with love and affection, so...

Answer (score 0):

There are only 4 ways to assign a pointer.

1) Make it a NULL pointer, which means you assign it to the value "0" or "NULL" like you have done.

2) You assign it to the address of the variable you wish to point to (since a pointer just points to an address in memory). This is what I believe you are trying to do. You would create an integer variable (int x = 0;) and then assign the pointer to the address(&) of x. (pi = &x).

3) You assign it to another pointer.

4)Utilize dynamic memory allocation.

To print the value that your pointer is pointing to, you would have to dereference it using the * character like this - "cout << *pi;    //prints 0"

"cout << pi; //doing this would print the actual address in memory"

Comment: Did you really test it? There is no output for *pi for me.

Comment: @B.Swan it is most likely because you have it assigned as a null pointer still. You need to assign it a value